# How to check if file (image) upload is completed

Tags: php

My scenario, user is posting data and image via android device on to server. I would like the script that handles upload to wait with the response until image is uploaded 100%.

Actually it's not clear to me, since I'm still a beginner, if this script does that already. 
When posting item via android, I receive the response pretty fast and image is between 1 and 2MB.

This is the script I'm using now:

```
<?php
/************************************************
    Required PHP Files
************************************************/
require_once("../models/funcs.php");
require_once("../models/db-settings.php");
/************************************************
    Functionality
************************************************/
$image_path = "../images/items/";
$image_name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];

$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

$query = ...

$result = $my_db->query($query);    

$image_path = $image_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $image_path) && !$my_db->error) {

    echo 200;

} else{

    echo 400;

    echo $my_db->error;
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path1;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how PHP has always worked. Your script is run only once upload is finished.

Only recently it's possible to monitor [file upload progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php).

Comment: And AJAX may be useful too to get a progress bar.